# How to display submission data on a thank you page with sprout forms?

Tags: plugin-sproutforms

How can the thank you page display submitted values? I'd like to give the users the submission id to reference.

I've tried adding a hidden redirect field with a shortcode GET parameter but haven't got the syntax right.

Comment: Is `{{ craft.app.request.getParam('paramName') }}` ([docs](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-web-twig-variables-request.html#method-getparam)) what you're after?

Comment: That gets me a lot closer to a work around, but I'm trying to get the new submission's id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can grab the [last submitted entry](https://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/docs/forms/entries.html#lastentry) on the thank you page. So using the example, you should be able to do `lastEntry.id`

Comment: That'd do the trick, but it's a wee bit hinky. The page would always have the most recent submission's content.

Comment: Isn’t that what you wanted? Or can a user submit multiple times, and you want to show all their submissions?

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding, the thank you page would always display the latest submission's content regardless of the user viewing it.

Comment: I’m pretty sure it would be the last submission of that user (otherwise that is a huge security issue), but check with the developer to be sure.

Comment: I just checked the code and yes, it only gets the last entry for that session, so you’re good to go!